# git log the difference between 1 branch from another

Tags: git, git-merge, git-log

I have 2 branches A and B.

Whenever I run a build, Branch A gets merged into Branch B. I want to be able to email out all the updates made in A, since the last time the build was ran.  How can I use `git log` to be able to copy all the commits made in A since the last A -> B merge?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

That'll be

```
git log B..A
```

E.g. "display all commits that are in A but not in B" Or if you wish to do it against non local branches

```
git log origin/B..origin/A
```

Comment: @Jakub I think the proper link is now http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_commit_ranges

Comment: How to apply the commit from the git log output so that both branch will have same commits?

Answer (score 22):

An alternative syntax would be to use:

```
$ git log refA refB --not refC
```

or in your case of comparing only two branches

```
$ git log A --not B
```

Also from the [GIT SCM Commit Ranges Docs](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges)

When comparing two branches it really comes down to preference. I just find this a bit more readable and don't have to worry about confusing `A...B` with `A..B` (also mentioned in the docs).